# Reasonable VMware Memory Overcommit Ratio?

Tags: vmware-esxi, memory, vmware-vsphere

As a "rule of thumb" what is considered a balanced VMware **memory overcommit** ratio?

I could find official guidelines for vCPU:pCPU ratio but not for vMemory:pMemory.

Comment: There is none. It depends on your load. Measure it over time and scale accordingly.

Comment: usually in a perfect world, would be the answer ZERO

Answer (score 1):

1/1. Do not overcommit memory.